# How to sort all lists in a specific bin in Aerospike using aql?

Tags: aerospike, aql

I have a few question about ordered lists in Aerospike:

1. How can I see in the DB, using aql, if the list is ordered or not?
2. Does ordered list means it’s sorted?
3. I want to scan the db and change all lists (in a specific bin) to be ordered. I want to do is using [set_type](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/cdt-list-ops.html#setType), but I can’t seem to make it work. Is that possible? how can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Cross linked here:https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/list-oprations/5282

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm posting my answer from your cross-posted question here https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/list-oprations/5282:

You could scan the namespace with a [`ScanPolicy.includeBinData=false`](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/policy/ScanPolicy.html#includeBinData) and for each record digest you get back use `operate()` to wrap the following operations into a single transaction:

- [`ListOperation.setOrder()`](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/cdt/ListOperation.html#setOrder(java.lang.String,%20com.aerospike.client.cdt.ListOrder)) to [`ListOrder.ORDERED`](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/cdt/ListOrder.html#ORDERED)
- [`ListOperation.sort()`](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/cdt/ListOperation.html#sort(java.lang.String,%20int)) with a [`ListSortFlags.DROP_DUPLICATES`](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/cdt/ListSortFlags.html#DROP_DUPLICATES)

You will only need to run this once to clean up your database.

The ordering type will stick for all future operations. You'd just continue to use the `ListWriteFlags.ADD_UNIQUE` list policy.

This is for the Java client, but all other clients have these operations and policies in them.

Comment: All future operations .. on those records that you just updated. If you insert new records, must use the correct flags again.  Correct?

Comment: As far as I know? Doesn’t hurt to be explicit, but I’ll check

Answer (score 2):

I don't think AQL is the right tool to exploit the full power of lists. Perhaps it is not yet updated to the full functionality of lists. It is built on top of the C client.  At least AQL ver 3.15.2.1 that I checked with is not.  You might want to write a java client application.